# 401 Unauthorized error when calling laravel API trough AJAX datatable

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, http, datatable

I've setup an auth system in laravel which works fine. I've created a rest api to call some data, the route of this api is protected by the auth middleware and an api guard with a token driver.

```
'admin-api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
```

I have a filed in my admins table called api_token, contains a token for each admin
if I call this api in postman and pass the bearer token in authorization tab, it works fine and retrieve the data

However, I'm trying to call the same API through AJAX datatable and I pass the exact same bearer token but it keeps showing 401 Unauthoriszed error in Chrome console.

Can someone explain why the token is not passed to the api call and how to make it pass?

my api.php file:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:admin-api'], function(){
    
    Route::get('/admins', [APIController::class, 'getAdmins'])->name('getAdmins');

});
```

my api controller method which calls the data from the database:

```
public function getAdmins(){  
        $query = AdminResource::collection(Admin::all());
        return datatables($query)->make(true);
    }
```

my ajax code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            // DataTable
            $('#dataTable').DataTable({
                headers: {
                    'X-Authorization': 'odhTIEX6PP4oBwC39JFpAbWF8TaZ5iL8JkB0PMd4Lg9WrbQFgqwT5k9pzPw9iWdS3jYFmNcoJrnydgaM',
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer odhTIEX6PP4oBwC39JFpAbWF8TaZ5iL8JkB0PMd4Lg9WrbQFgqwT5k9pzPw9iWdS3jYFmNcoJrnydgaM',
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
                    'Accept': 'application/json',

                },
                processing: true,
                'language': {
                    'loadingRecords': '&nbsp;',
                    'processing': '<div class="spinner-border text-primary"></div>'
                },
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: "{{ route('getAdmins') }}",

                columns: [{
                        data: 'first_name'
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'last_name'
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'email'
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'phone'
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'role'
                    },
                ]
            });

        });

    </script>
```